# Internet Explorer 11 gives me a SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. on line 1 character 1 of my ASPX page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, webforms

I have a webpage which loads mostly fine in IE11, but for some reason there is an error:

> SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.

on the page at line 1 character 1. Looking at the page in the IE debugger, I see a blank line before the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration, but in the actual ASPX file all that is there is some VB code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="iso-8859-1" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="xxx" TagName="UserHeader" Src="UserHeader.ascx" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="XXXDBTools" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="XXXStrTools" %>
<script runat="server">
    Dim myTempConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim myTempCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim myTempReader as SqlDataReader
    ' etc
</script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!-- etc -->
```

The page works just fine in all browsers apart from IE that I've tested (Firefox, Chrome, and Edge). It's just IE that has issues; what happens is that due to this script error, a spinner icon that is supposed to disappear when the page is finished loading never disappears, which is rather annoying.

How can I fix the page in IE so it doesn't give an error and crash before it gets to the code where the spinner is disabled?

Comment: Can you please try to move doctype line above all other code. Or remove any whitespace at the end of your serverside code if it exists.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side, the posted code seems works well. Is there any other code? Generally the Page property like this `<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="VBWebApplication2.WebForm1">`, you could try to create a new web page to test.

Comment: Yeah, it magically started working eventually; not sure what was going on there!